# How to debug a referenced assembly in Xamarin.Android project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android, visual-studio-debugging

I am testing out Xamarin.Android via Visual Studio 2010.

My Xamarin.Android VS2010 Solution contains two projects: The Android project and a project (I'll call it MyProject for this post) that does all the business logic for the demo app that I'm making - The Android project references the MyProject project/assembly).

When I run the appliation, I am receiving an exception error in MyProject and, so, I would like to step into MyProject and debug the problem.

However, when I debug, VS2010 is not stepping into MyProject.

For example:

In my Android project I have a breakpoint at the location of the exception:

```
MyProject mp= new MyProject();
mp.DoSomething(); // Exception is thrown here, breakpoint is set here, but VS doesn't step into the MyProject code. The debugger gets stuck here and displays exception info in the Output window.
```

What do I need to do to debug a referenced project/assembly in my VS2010 Mono Android project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason I was unable to debug the referenced assembly was due to the fact that my referenced assembly was a .NET assembly - an assembly written in C# which referenced .NET assemblies.

Being new to Xamarin.Android development, I assumed that I could create an Android project and then simply reference an existing .NET project to the Android project - this is not the case.

In order to reference a .NET assembly in an Android project (and thereby debug the .NET assembly) I had to:

1. In Visual Studio (or Xamarin Studio for that matter), create a new Android Class Library project
2. Copy all the .cs files from the .NET project into the newly created Android Class Library
3. Build/Compile the Android Class Library. At this point you may need to manually add a reference to a Mono assembly that wasn't added to the project by default. For example: I had to manually add the Mono `System.Data` assembly.
4. In the original Android Project, reference the Android Class Library
5. Done

The important thing to understand (which I didn't) is that Xamarin has created Mono assemblies which correspond to the .NET assemblies. The Mono assemblies exist (on my machine) in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\` while the .NET assemblies exist (on my machine) in '(i.e. assemblies found within the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0` directory)'.

On that note - If an Android project is referencing an assembly/project that uses the .NET assemblies, you will receive a Warning that states

> "The project 'MyProject' cannot be referenced. The referenced project is targeted
>   to a different framework family (.NETFramework)"