# Debug Xamarin Plugin project on Android devices

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

Thanks for helping me with this in advance.

We have a large application that we ported to Xamarin for being used on Android devices only.
This application is capable of loading plugins.

Today when we customize the application for a specific customer, we create plugins projects and reference them in the host application which is also the main project of the resulting APK. We have to do this, because this way the plugin dll is being part of the APK and we are able to debug from Visual Studio.

For the future, we want to decouple this. We learned so far that we can push our plugin dlls to the APK as part of a build script with aapt.exe. This way we get a single APK that we are able to give to the customers. That's fine for a release.

But my question is, is it possible to create a single plugin project, write the code, and debug this dll against a specific APK on a device? Like it is possible on windows with the attach to process functionality? Perhaps it possible to play with the build events and aapt the dll in an existing APK, deploy it to the device, and debug.

Help is very welcome. I read a lot, but have no clue how to start on this...

Thanks T4E

Comment: Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327888/how-to-debug-a-referenced-assembly-in-xamarin-android-project

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me on this. But the refered question / answer does not fit exactly my question.